# How to implement this query using Zend_Db?

Tags: zend-framework

SELECT
name,
(CASE due WHEN ' ' THEN ' ' ELSE FROM_UNIXTIME(due/1000000) END) AS 'due',
(CASE due WHEN ' ' THEN ' ' ELSE DATEDIFF(NOW(), FROM_UNIXTIME(due/1000000)) END) AS 'Day Ago',
(CASE due WHEN ' ' THEN ' ' ELSE FROM_UNIXTIME(completed/1000000) END) AS 'completed',
description
FROM milestone 
WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), FROM_UNIXTIME(due/1000000) > 1;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$dbAdapter->query($sqlQuery)
```

Where `$sqlQuery` contains the string you posted :) Far te easiest solution for such a complex query ;) Or

```
$db->select()
   ->from('milestone', array(new Zend_Db_Expr($stringBetweenSelectAndFrom)))
   ->where('DATEDIFF(NOW(), FROM_UNIXTIME(due/1000000) > 1);
```